# C++ static storage pointer to dynamic storage

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have an automatically allocated pointer in static storage

```
int* p[2];
```

and I do:

```
int i;
p[0] = &i;
p[1] = new int;
```

This gives me an array of automatically allocated pointers in static storage to an int in static storage and an unnamed int in dynamic storage.

Is this correct, good practice and do I have to delete `p[1]` since it points to an address in dynamic storage?

Comment: ***Is this correct, good practice and do I have to delete p[1] since it points to an address in dynamic storage?*** Yes, you need to `delete` what you `new` othewise you will have a memory leak

Comment: @lasbr It is not a good practice because it will be difficult to determine which element of the array points to the dynamically allocated memory and which does not.

Comment: It's not only good practice to delete what you have allocated with new, but you _must_ do it. But it's very bad practice (or even completly wrong) to store pointers to memory allocated with new in the same array as pointers to static data.

Comment: @drescherjm @Jabberwocky How can I delete p[1]? Simply doing `delete p[1]` does not work. It gives me an `invalid pointer` error

Comment: If `delete p[1]` fails, then you do something bad in the code you don't show us. Please post a new question about that error, with a proper [mre].

Comment: @lasbr With the code in your question you can simply `delete p[1];` no problem, but can't have `delete p[0];` because this will try to delete variable that has not been allocated via `new` and this is undefined behaviour (resulting mostly in crashes or other strange behaviour).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @Jabberwocky Alright. I got it working, thank you. My problem was, that I tried to assign two pointers in one line, i.e. `p[0], p[1] = new int;` which apparently does not work

Comment: @lasbr read about the comma operator in your C book. But `new int;` is pretty pointless anyway, it allocates memory for a single `int` which is not really useful. But admittedly I don't now your usecase, but it really looks fishy.

Comment: @Jabberwocky My use case is actually just some weird pointer chains for some university assignment. I guess it is not about practical real world C++ programming scenarios

Answer (score 1):

If you `new` something you have to `delete` it. Always.

Beyond that, yes, you can store pointers in the same array that point to data with different kinds of lifetimes. Whether this is a good idea depends on what you are doing; although, most likely it is not.